# How to solve out of domain error in mathprog?

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, ampl, energy, mathprog

H= 1..24;
s.t. ElectBattery{h in H}: ES[h]-ES[h-1]-P2S[h]*Efi['ESt']+PGEN['ESt',h]==0;

error: ES[0] out of domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

1. Make sure `ES[h]` is defined over `0..24` (instead of `1..24`)
2. Fix `ES[0]` to a known value by adding a constraint `ES[0]=10` (say).

If you want a steady-state solution, use:

2. `ES[0] = ES[24]`

Instead of this, you can also use an if-then-else construct like:

```
ES[h] - (if h=1 then ES[24] else ES[h-1]) - ..
```

Comment: 2. I want a stady state solution and i wrote the same E(0) = E(24) and it said then ES is already define. But the second choice you put works  perfect 